# testing with mocha: descibe is not defined

Tags: javascript, testing, meteor, mocha.js

I have a problem with testing Meteor. I have just started with this framework and I'm following the official tutorial to create the sample to-do app.
During this passage: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/testing the tutorial explain how to install the mocha package for meteor and how to run the test, the problem is that after finishing all the passages (the code is the same as the tutorial) I run the meteor server with the test command (meteor test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha) but I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: descibe is not defined
    at Suite.<anonymous> (imports/api/tasks.tests.js:9:9)
    at context.describe.context.context (/Users/ste/.meteor/packages/practicalmeteor_mocha-core/.1.0.1.yt8rvz++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/bdd.js:47:10)
    at meteorInstall.imports.api.tasks.tests.js (imports/api/tasks.tests.js:8:5)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:197:9)
    at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:120:16)
    at /private/var/folders/6b/vnbc8yxx3pv21r1bt6_1kvkr0000gn/T/meteor-test-runr4itrg/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js:191:1
    at /private/var/folders/6b/vnbc8yxx3pv21r1bt6_1kvkr0000gn/T/meteor-test-runr4itrg/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:303:34
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/ste/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.3_2.p6z7ay++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /private/var/folders/6b/vnbc8yxx3pv21r1bt6_1kvkr0000gn/T/meteor-test-runr4itrg/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:128:5
Exited with code: 1
```

Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
How can I fix this?

Comment: you mistype "describe" somewhere (miss 'r')

Comment: You are right, it's 2 hours that I'm to solve this bug -_-'
Thanks sir